# Prove that K is unbounded set.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be the set of all functions in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx<1$.

Consider in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$  the sup norm: $\left \| f \right \|=\displaystyle \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$. Show that $K$ is unbounded set.

My attempt: Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ such that $f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{n+x}, \ \forall x\in [0,1],\ n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, $f_n \in \mathcal{C}[0,1],\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{(n+x)^2}dx=-\dfrac{1}{n+x}|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}<1,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Therefore, $f_n\in K,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, $\left \| f_n \right \|=\displaystyle \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left |\dfrac{1}{n+x}  \right |=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+x}\right) \leq \dfrac{1}{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$

?????????

Any hint you can give me to follow correctly? Best Regards.

Comment: You have to either prove that $K$ is bouded or give an example of a  sequence $f_n$ in it whose norms tend to $\infty$. Just showing that a particular sequence in $K$ tends to $0$ does not prove anything.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt n x^{n}$ Then $\int_0^{1} |f_n(x)|^{2}=n\frac  1 {2n+1} <1$ for all $n$. But $\|f_n\| \geq f_n(1) =\sqrt n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a doubt: we have $\left \| f_n \right \|=\displaystyle \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\sqrt{n}x^n|=\sqrt{n}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|x^n|$. But why $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|x^n|\geq 1$ and not $=1$ only? .

Comment: @user_11111100010 Yes, $sup_{x \in [0,1]} |x^{n}|=1$. But that doesn't make it wrong to say that $sup_{x \in [0,1]} |x^{n}|\geq 1$.  For  my arguement I needed just $\geq 1$ so I wrote that.